# How to clone elements that have been bound by a jQuery UI Widget?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, clone

The following code fails to properly clone the input element. Clicking/focusing on the cloned input opens the datepicker on the original input.

http://jsfiddle.net/musicisair/YUkZw/

```
<input>
<script>
    var input = $("input").datepicker();
    $("body").append("<br>Input 2: ").append(
        input.clone(true);
    );
</script>
```

Is there a correct way of cloning elements that have been bound with a jQuery UI widget? If so, what is is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Normally, any event handlers bound to the original element are not
>   copied to the clone. The optional withDataAndEvents parameter allows
>   us to change this behavior, and to instead make copies of all of the
>   event handlers as well, bound to the new copy of the element. As of
>   jQuery 1.4, all element data (attached by the .data() method) is also
>   copied to the new copy.
>
> However, objects and arrays within element data are not copied and
>   will continue to be shared between the cloned element and the original
>   element. To deep copy all data, copy each one manually:

```
var $elem = $('#elem').data( "arr": [ 1 ] ), // Original element with attached data
    $clone = $elem.clone( true )
    .data( "arr", $.extend( [], $elem.data("arr") ) ); // Deep copy to prevent data sharing
```

> As of jQuery 1.5, withDataAndEvents can be optionally enhanced with
>   deepWithDataAndEvents to copy the events and data for all children of
>   the cloned element.

*Source: http://api.jquery.com/clone/*

I believe you are looking for the code above that actually copies the data associated with an element rather than sharing the data between elements.

## Update

After messing around a few minutes with this here's what I came up with:

```
//create original datepicker
var $input = $("input").datepicker(),

//clone the datepicker, copy the data from the original, and change the ID of the new element
    $clone = $input.clone(true).data( "datepicker", $.extend( true, {}, $input.data("datepicker") ) ).attr('id', 'test-id');

//now change the references in the data for the clone to point to the clone
$clone.data('datepicker').input = $clone;
$clone.data('datepicker').id = 'test-id';


//add the clone to the DOM
$("body").append("<br><br><br>Input 2: ").append(
    $clone
);
​
```

And a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YUkZw/5/

Comment: @SKS Thanks for your comment. I pasted in the wrong code, if you extend the `datepicker` data for the clone rather than just copying it then each element gets its own set of data (see: http://jsfiddle.net/YUkZw/5/). Then for the clone you have to set the references in it's `datepicker` data to reference the clone.

Comment: haha.. you did it.. but isn't it too much work.. I would rather recommend initializing datapicker again on input 2 :P.. Good job tho. +1

Comment: @SKS I agree, but it was still fun to figure out :)

Comment: This looks very promising. I wonder if `$.fn.clone` can be extended so that  `deep` (deepWithDataAndEvents) cloning will take care of this automatically. My use case is much more complex than the jsFiddle example I supplied in the question.

Comment: @DavidMurdoch You could create your own function that utilizes `.clone()`: `$.fn.customClone = function ($ele) { return $ele.clone(true); }`. Of course this example doesn't do any good, but you can do the extra work inside this custom function so you can just call `$clone = $input.customClone();`.

Comment: I ended up using this. The jQuery function that is responsible for deep cloning data and events (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L406) is private so duck-punching it to get it to behave properly would take more code than the actual plugin I'm writing.

Comment: it does not work for me. I tried to clone a kendo scheduler but somehow, references still point to the original scheduler as the OP has described.

Comment: @AGuyCalledGerald I'm not familiar with that product. This answer is pretty specific with the jQuery UI Datepicker references it changes on the clone. Do you have a fiddle or some error(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my trick.

If you have to clone an element which has a widget, don't bind the widget on *document.ready*. Instead, regenerate widget every time when the elements get focus.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[type=date]").focusin(function(){
        $("[type=date]").not(this).datepicker("destroy");
        if($(this).data("datepicker") == null) {
            $(this).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
        }
    });
});
```