# Adding new row, binding of datepicker to cloumn works in weird manner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to add a new row on button click. In my new row there is one Textbox with which I want to bind datepicker but not able to. Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
<table>
     <tr>
     <td><button type="button" onClick ="addRow(this)">Add</button></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><input type="text" name="installDate" value="" class ="date"/> </td>        
     </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).on('click', function() {
$('.date').each(function() {
        $(this).datepicker();
});
});

function addRow(btn) {         
    var parentRow = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
    var table = parentRow.parentNode;
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var lastRow = table.rows[rowCount - 1];
    var rowClone = lastRow.cloneNode(true);
    table.appendChild(rowClone);
    $('.date', rowClone).datepicker(); // Code to fix the problem
}
```

Seq1: Add Row => Click on textbox of newRow, calender pops up and everything works fine.

Seq2: 
1. Click on document and then try on textbox of original row, then calender pops up.
2. Add new row.
3. now click on textbox of new row, calender never pops up to select the date.

Attaching JSFiddle for reference
http://jsfiddle.net/wAyhm/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

[How to clone elements that have been bound by a jQuery UI Widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725488/how-to-clone-elements-that-have-been-bound-by-a-jquery-ui-widget/9725550#9725550)

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Meligy/DKtA6/6/

```
window. addRow = function addRow(btn) {         
    var parentRow = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
    var table = parentRow.parentNode;
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var lastRow = table.rows[rowCount - 1];
    var lastDatePicker = $('.date', lastRow);
    var rowClone = $(lastRow).clone(true);
    var datePickerClone = $('.date', rowClone);
    var datePickerCloneId = 'test-id' + rowCount;
    datePickerClone.data( "datepicker", 
        $.extend( true, {}, lastDatePicker.data("datepicker") ) 
    ).attr('id', datePickerCloneId);
    datePickerClone.data('datepicker').input = datePickerClone;
    datePickerClone.data('datepicker').id = datePickerCloneId;
    $(table).append(rowClone);
    datePickerClone.datepicker();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. In reality I need to clone the column, will the same solution work for column clone as well ?

Comment: Well, it should, the parts that matter are after you clone. You copy the `data` properties, and create a unique ID and then map the `id` and this `input` property to the new textbox clone.